# Https Hostname not verified using goDaddy certs

Tags: java, android, ssl-certificate, bouncycastle, httpsurlconnection

I am trying to access my server using two of the goDaddy certificates that are listed under my endpoint. The three certs in the stack are My cert > Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority -G2 > Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2. I downloaded both the secure and root certs from the Go Daddy Repository and now have added both to my android app raw resource folder. Even with both in there it still gives me this error

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname  not verified:
```

I don't know what i should do next. I tried a lot of combinations so I think i need a different way of doing this.

Here is what I have so far;
My HttpsClient code;

```
public class MyHttpsGet extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

Context context;

int cert;
int interCert;
boolean allowHost;
private String username;
private String password;

//this is used if you need a password and username
//mainly for logins to a webserver
public MyHttpsGet(String username, String password, Context context, int cert, int intermedCert)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.cert = cert;
    this.interCert = intermedCert;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;

}

//used for image downloading
public MyHttpsGet(){}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String url = params[0];
    return httpsDownloadData(url, context, cert, interCert);
}

public String httpsDownloadData (String urlString, Context context, int certRawResId, int certIntermedResId)
{
    String respone = null;

    try {
        // build key store with ca certificate
        KeyStore keyStore = buildKeyStore(context, certRawResId, certIntermedResId);


        // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);

        // Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        // Create a connection from url
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        if (username != null) {
            Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());
                }
            });
        }
        HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());


        int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        Log.d("Status code: ", Integer.toString(statusCode));


        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        if (inputStream != null) {
            respone = streamToString(inputStream);
            inputStream.close();
        }

    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.d("MyHttps Respones: ", respone);
    return respone;
}


private static KeyStore buildKeyStore(Context context, int certRawResId, int interCert){
    // init a default key store
    String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
    KeyStore keyStore = null;
    try {
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        keyStore.load(null, null);

        // read and add certificate authority
        Certificate cert2 = readCert(context, interCert);
        Certificate cert = readCert(context, certRawResId);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca" , cert2);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", cert);



    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return keyStore;

}

private static Certificate readCert(Context context, int certResourceId) throws IOException {

    // read certificate resource
    InputStream caInput = context.getResources().openRawResource(certResourceId);

    Certificate ca = null;
    try {
        // generate a certificate
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        caInput.close();
    }

    return ca;
}

//this is used for downloading strings from an http or https connection
private String streamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}


 }
```

And here is how I call it/use it:

```
 MyHttpsGet task = new MyHttpsGet(username, password,myContext, R.raw.gdroot_g2, R.raw.gdintermed);
        try {
            myJson = task.execute(myUrl).get();
            Log.d("Json: " , myJson);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        new runningMan().execute();
```

Thank you for any help with this.

Here is a picture of my Cert Chain
[image]

Comment: What web server are you using? have you bundled all root certificates on the server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says `apivitacrm.elasticbeanstalk.com`, but you then black out the wildcard name in your certificate. Why?

Well, regardless of what it is, it looks like it starts with an `a`, so it is definitely not a `*.elasticbeanstalk.com` wildcard certificate.

That means that the error message is correct. The certificate does not belong to the domain name given.

Even if it is a `*.apivitacrm.elasticbeanstalk.com` wildcard (blackout doesn't seem wide enough for that, though), it still wouldn't match `apivitacrm.elasticbeanstalk.com`, since it only matches subdomains.